# Is it possible to access the window object of a web page from an extension script?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I realize extensions are sandboxed to prevent collisions, but is there any way to access a web page's global objects from an extension script (i.e., not the extension's global HTML page, but the actual page that is loaded in the tab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible -- and this may be the only way -- for an extension to access a web page's globals by inserting a `<script>` element into the DOM. Conversely, however, the inserted script will not be able to access the *extension's* objects.

Comment: I figured this was the case, but thanks for the confirmation. Do you know if this is just an unfortunate limitation of the API or if there's an actual security reason for preventing access to the web page's globals?